# Schedule restart of Akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-supervision

Is anyone aware of a way to create a SupervisorStrategy that executes a Restart of an Actor after a delay? To provide some context I have an actor that queries a DB on startup. If the DB connection is down the Actor will spin until it hits the max retried. It would be nice to delay the restart.

A brute force but unacceptable solution is to do something like the following:

```
override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 minute)    
  {
    case initEx: ActorInitializationException => {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      Restart
    }
    case t =>
      super.supervisorStrategy.decider.applyOrElse(t, (_: Any) => Escalate)
  }
```

However, this seems untenable to me as I want to avoid any blocking code.

Is this just not a concept that should be supported by actors? Should the delay or retry be moved into the Actor implementation itself? This seems counter to the idea of 'let it crash'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay on restart hasn't been implemented yet. Thread.sleep is out of the question performance wise.

I see two choices :

- Have your main actor create the querying actor on a message. When it blows up because of a database outage, you can just stop the actor and [re-schedule](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/scheduler.html) a message to recreate it. Might be a problem if database operations must occur before anything else.
- Move the fault tolerance logic inside the querying actor. Have your database logic inside a partial function and use a [circuit breaker](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/common/circuitbreaker.html) to handle retries. You can then use supervision to Restart the actor on needed exceptions and through preRestart hook re-schedule the message instructing to do database operations. If you don't want to restart, just surround your circuit breaker with a try-catch to re-schedule the message here.

Comment: I've decided to go with the first option. This works ok, however it's not without it's limitations. The main issue is that by rescheduling an Init message to create the actor (as opposed to using Restart) results in the child actor being created again from scratch (as opposed to Recreated). This means you lose the built in maxNrOfRetries functionality and have handle this yourself. Looking forward to delayed restart being implemented as a feature.